# how and where i can run gradlew clean war windows

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to setup Apache RAT insalation instration has given below

```
Extract the archive file to your local directory.
Download gradle-wrapper.jar version 2.10 and place it in the fineract-provider/gradle/wrapper folder. See 'Instructions to download gradle wrapper' above.
```

Run `./gradlew clean war` or .`/gradlew build` to build deploy-able war file which will be created at build/libs directory.

I have Apache RAT in the path like  `D:\apache-rat-0.12` and `gradle-wrapper.jar` in the path like  `D:\fineract-provider\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar`

My question is how and where i can run Run `./gradlew clean war` I tried running.

Answer (score 0):

There should also be a `gradlew` file in the `D:\fineract-provider` folder. You'd run from this directory